# How to show all traffic after selecting "Show Only Process = #####" in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I'm using fiddler and I filtered the list of requests by right-clicking in the traffic list and selecting "Filter Now > Show Only Process="

**How to I remove this filter so I can see all entries again?**

For the life of me I can't figure it out!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the applied filter "down under":

[image]